Install kerberos packages using paramiko
I'm trying to automate installation of kerberos packages (krb5-kdc, krb5-admin-server, krb5-user) using python-paramiko library on Ubuntu server.
Ref article: https://www.atlantic.net/dedicated-server-hosting/how-to-setup-kerberos-server-and-client-on-ubuntu/
When i send the command sudo apt install krb5-kdc krb5-admin-server krb5-user -y via ssh, an interactive screen pops up like below:
pop-up.png
So how to send input to this popup? I have tried multiple things and it doesn't seem to work.
I tried following code but it didn't work as expected and threw error.
            conn = paramiko.SSHClient()
            conn.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            conn.connect(host, username=user, password=psw, port=22)         
            chan = conn.invoke_shell()
            server_name = "example.demo.com"
            cmd = "sudo apt install krb5-kdc krb5-admin-server krb5-user -y"
            chan.send(f"{cmd}\n")
            support.wait_for_data(chan, output_list=["Default Kerberos version 5 realm:"])
            chan.send('DEMO.COM')
            chan.send("\n")
            support.wait_for_data(chan, output_list=["Kerberos servers for your realm:"])
            chan.send(f"{server_name}\n")
            support.wait_for_data(chan, output_list=["Administrative server for your Kerberos realm:"])
            chan.send(f"{server_name}\n")
            support.wait_for_data(chan, output_list=["Setting up a Kerberos Realm"])
            chan.send("\n")

def wait_for_data(
    chan: "paramiko.channel.Channel",
    output_list: list = None,
    verify_output: bool = True,
    timeout: int = 40,
):
    """
    Helper method to check if the channel is ready to receive data
    and verify expected data available or not

    :param chan: SSH shell channel
    :param output_list: Command output list to verify
    :param verify_output: If True, validate output.
    :param timeout: Timeout in seconds
    """
    stdout = b""
    while True:
        # Check if the channel is ready to receive data
        if chan.recv_ready():
            stdout += chan.recv(10000)

        if verify_output:
            for val in output_list:
                if val in common.to_str(stdout):
                    return common.to_str(stdout)
        time.sleep(1)
        timeout -= 1
        if not verify_output and timeout == 0:
            return common.to_str(stdout)
        if timeout <= 0:
            raise SSHError(
                f"Did not receive '{output_list}' as expected.\n"
                f"Shell output: {stdout}"
            )

When i run above code, it fails with below err:
exceptions.SSHError: Did not receive '['Kerberos servers for your realm:']' as expected. Shell output: b'DEMO.COM'

The proper fix is to populate the debconf database with the preferred settings prior to installing the packages. I'll mark this as a duplicate of a suitable question.
